# reactive website performance extremely poor when disconnected from the internet

Tags: networking, vuejs2

Strap in; this is a complex one...

I have a device which hosts a static vue2 website, and a rest API. Typically, this device is connected directly to a control laptop. The vue2 site is a control system for the device.  The site performs a status ping every second from the API, and updates based on the results returned.

Recently, after a sensor upgrade, I have observed that the reactivity is delayed (15-20 seconds to update UI appropriately after issuing a command). When a command is initiated through the API, if I query the API directly through another tab, the resulting json message suggests the device is working correctly (shows the correct state), but the site is not updating the UI based on that state for 15-20 seconds).

However, here is the interesting bit, if I connect the device and the computer to a switch which is connected to the internet, the reactivity is immediate and everything works as expected.

Points I can offer/troubleshooting I have performed:

- everything appears to work properly, it is just the website reactivity which is extremely delayed
- routing table does not appear to be the issue
- there are no certificates, everything is http
- the sensor is on a separate network interface from the control app
- device host operating system is ubuntu 16, control device has been tested with windows, OSX using Chrome, Safari and Edge, all showing similar results
- I've turned off all windows defender and browser security controls with no observed effect
- the device does not do any "DNS" based network calls.

Any ideas from anyone are welcome... its breaking my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.. typical, once I post the question..

The device had been renamed, and the /etc/hosts file didn't have the hostname added to the 127.0.0.1 entry.

When the device looks up the IP address of the hostname it will first
query the hosts file and, if not found, then query a DNS server on the
internet. Without a valid internet connection, it will take some time
for the DNS server query to time out. With the internet, it will get a
negative response quicker. If it has a valid line in the hosts file then
it will never try to query a DNS server.

The tell tail sign for me was a sudo command took a long time to request the password entry. Searching on this had a number of questions/answers related to ensuring the hostname is in the hosts file.